# Proper preprocessing in R

Tags: r

I have a  dataset like this

| FID | osmid | s | e | seg_length |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 4999 | 733 | 99 | 7.7 |
| 1 | 566 | 733 | 33 | 3.2 |
| 2 | 499 | 713 | 96 | 7.7 |
| 3 | 56 | 783 | 32 | 3.5 |
| 4 | 409 | 783 | 98 | 7.6 |
| 5 | 516 | 736 | 38 | 3.5 |
| 6 | 459 | 739 | 98 | 7.7 |
| 7 | 526 | 731 | 33 | 3.2 |

s stands for starting work and e for ending point. Some FID share the same start and end point. I want to keep only one start and end point for every point so when two starting point are shared I want to keep only these with the shortest seg_length. I could'nt find a good code for that.
Every end and start point should only have one unique value.

For example FID 0 and 1 share the same starting point and in the new dataset only FID 1 should be there. Also FID 4 and FID 6 share the same end point and in the new dataset only 4 should be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `slice_min` after grouping by 's'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(s) %>%
   slice_min(n = 1, order_by = seg_length) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 × 5
    FID osmid     s     e seg_length
  <int> <int> <int> <int>      <dbl>
1     2   499   713    96        7.7
2     7   526   731    33        3.2
3     1   566   733    33        3.2
4     5   516   736    38        3.5
5     6   459   739    98        7.7
6     3    56   783    32        3.5
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(FID = 0:7, osmid = c(4999L, 566L, 499L, 56L, 409L, 
516L, 459L, 526L), s = c(733L, 733L, 713L, 783L, 783L, 736L, 
739L, 731L), e = c(99L, 33L, 96L, 32L, 98L, 38L, 98L, 33L), seg_length = c(7.7, 
3.2, 7.7, 3.5, 7.7, 3.5, 7.7, 3.2)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Answer (score 1):

We could group and then filter by `min(seg_length)`:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  group_by(s) %>% 
  filter(seg_length == min(seg_length)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

```
   FID osmid     s     e seg_length
  <int> <int> <int> <int>      <dbl>
1     1   566   733    33        3.2
2     2   499   713    96        7.7
3     3    56   783    32        3.5
4     5   516   736    38        3.5
5     6   459   739    98        7.7
6     7   526   731    33        3.2
```